# extract all the files in the folder using php

Tags: php, extract

I want to extract all the zip files inside a folder. So please check my below snippet and assist me.

```
<?php
$path='C:\xampp\htdocs\m'; // folder name 
if ($handle = opendir($path)){
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
        if ('.' === $file) continue;
        if ('..' === $file) continue;
        //echo "filename: ".$file."<br />";

        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $res = $zip->open($file);
        if ($res === TRUE){
            $zip->extractTo($path);   // extract it to the path 
            $zip->close();
            echo " Done! $file extracted to $dir"; // done
        } 
        else{
            echo "opps! I couldn't open $file"; // no
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Define "did not work".  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @user1682578 did you checked my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below snippet. Below script will find all the zips inside folder and extract it in the dynamically created folder.

```
<?php
//Zip file path`
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/m/';

foreach (glob($path."*.zip") as $filename) {        
    //Destination folder to save extract zip file
    $dest = $path.basename($filename, ".zip");

    //create folder to extract zip file in it.
    mkdir($dest,"0777");
    //Check wether the zip file exist or not.
    if (file_exists($path.$filename)) {
        //create object of ZipArchive class
        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        //Open zip file`
        $res = $zip->open($path.$filename);

        if ($res === TRUE){
            //extract zip file in destination folder`
            $zip->extractTo($dest);   // extract it to the path 
            //close zip file after extracted.
            $zip->close();
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I did use your code but there is some problem Notice: Undefined index: C:/xampp/htdocs/kmzt in C:\xampp\htdocs\t2.php on line 3

Comment: what should write in DOCUMENT_ROOT'

Comment: @user1682578 Have you placed all your zip files in C:\xampp\htdocs\m folder?

Comment: I change the name of folder m with kmzt  , yes I place them all in kmzt

Comment: Then please change $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/m/'; to $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/kmzt/';

Comment: Can you please update 
foreach (glob("*.zip") as $filename) {  line with 
foreach (glob($path."*.zip") as $filename) {

I have updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use glob();

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: <?php

$path='C:\xampp\htdocs\kmzt'; // folder name 

if ($handle = opendir($path)){

foreach (glob("*.zip") as $filename) {
 
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
//echo "filename: ".$file."<br />";
 
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($filename);
if ($res === TRUE)
 {
$zip->extractTo($path);   // extract it to the path 
$zip->close();

 echo " Done! $filename extracted "; // done
 
}
}
 echo "fail loop"; 
}
else{
            echo "fail"; // no
        }


   





?>


after run the code they did not enter the loop ?